# Inertia for dragging in D3 version 2

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement inertia for drag using D3 version 2.

The latest version of d3 (3.3.10) from the download page does not have it, while pjanik has modified a version of d3 which does that - http://bl.ocks.org/pjanik/raw/5872514/

In any case, how can I implement this in D3 version 2?

---

A very primitive function to achieve the feel, but would really prefer an elegant formula if anyone has any suggestions, much appreciated:

```
function inertia(value) {
    var remainder = value,
        output,
        drag = 0.3,
        stepTime = 60

    //var x = 0
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        output = remainder * drag  

        //x += output
        //console.log(x)              
        //jQuery('.logo').css('margin-left', x)

        console.log(output)  
        remainder = remainder - output

        /*a hack to clear when value is small*/
        if (output < value * .005) 
          clearInterval(interval)

    }, stepTime)
}

//Any integer to be split for steps, can be distance, time, any value!
inertia(100)
```

Comment: Thinking of using jQuery animate/step to animate a value without targeting a DOM, is that possible?

Comment: Trying to animate-shift the chart domain

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use version 2? Have you tried applying the patch you've mentioned to version 2?

Comment: Topology hangs/becomes very slow or unstable on zooming in/out (without errors), when I last tried upgrading to version 3. Everywhere else seems to be fine.. following the upgrade guide.

It's also sizeable solution which implements d3 in several places, and I don't have the luxury or justification for more time for the upgrade at the moment.

Comment: I created a script that simulates momentum (inertia) scrolling in jQuery, including custom easing. I think the inertia principle I use will help you out (or at least inspire you). The script is fully explained and annotated on my website: http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/simulate-momentum-scrolling-in-jquery/